# Root on Android x86_64

Tags: rooting, root-access, android-x86

I have an Intel development board with an Atom processor running Android 6.0.1 and kernel version 3.14.64-x86_64. I can adb into the board and gain superuser privileges by typing su (su binary in /system/xbin), but any application requiring root permission does not run. RootChecker says that the device is not rooted. How can I run apps requiring root permission? do I have to root it some other way?

Comment: Is there any **su** file under **/system/bin**?

Comment: su binary is in /system/xbin not in /system/bin

Comment: Please notice that I specifically asked if there's any file called **su**, under **/system/bin**. I'm perfectly aware that your **su binary** is placed inside **/system/xbin**, as it should be.

Comment: No, there is no file called su under /system/bin

Comment: If we are lucky, then this may be the culprit. From a root shell, issue the following commands: `ln -s /system/xbin/su /system/bin/su`, `chown 0.0 /system/bin/su`, `chmod 777 /system/bin/su`. Once you performed those, reboot your device and check again with RootChecker.

Comment: I ran all the commands and rebooted. Still no root. Should I install Superuser apk as well?

Comment: You could, but I don't think it'll made much of a difference.

Comment: installing the apk did not make a difference still no root. It did say that the SU binary needs to be updated, but continuing with the update does nothing. It just says failed

Comment: also after running the commands. i am unable to SU in the shell get the following message
`su: setgid failed: Operation not permitted`

Comment: I also have the source code for the android build running on the dev board. Can it be modified to allow root to other applications?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I've never had the occasion to build Android from source, hence any suggestion I may advance will be purely hypothetical. Also, since I cannot reproduce a situation that's similar to yours, I guess that it'd be best to wait for other experts in the field.